# Cannot remove weird space in masonry

Tags: jquery, html, css, masonry

I'm trying to help my friend with his page. This is the url:

http://lukaszgawronski.com/web/

as you will see after page load, there is a very nice spacing between columns (it's ok), but much bigger there is a gap between rows/images.

I mean this space:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VwXYc.jpg

I've tried with bunch of css code lines, setting margin:0/padding:0, but without success. Any ideas how to fix that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this 
go to http://lukaszgawronski.com/web/wp-content/themes/grille/style.css

add this at the end of it

```
.isotope-item {

    margin: 0 20px 0;

}
```

Comment: Happy that i could help:)